# Почему ldconfig не видит мои библиотеки?

Tags: linux

Скомпилировал shared(*.so) библиотеки и положил в `usr/lib`. Выполнил команду `ldconfig -p | grep имя_библиотеки` и ничего. Перезагрузил систему, тоже ничего.
А другие библиотеки из это папки видит и путь до них показывает. Почему linux не видит мои библиотеки?

Comment: 1. программа linux тут абсолютно не при чём. 2. опцией `-p` вы только выводите содержимое кэша загрузчика. чтобы обновить кэш, запустите программу *ldconfig* без аргументов.